# saving the actual date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
         submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            value2=null;
            //value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            value2=newNumber.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: the value 2 is: "+value2);
            type=spin;

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: the type is "+type);

            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            myRef.child(type).updateChildren(map);


            DatabaseReference newRef=myRef.child(type);


            newRef.push().setValue(value2);
```

I was trying to save the actual date, but when I click the button nothing happens, but when I remove the Map it actually works.

Comment: the database isn't changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to be sure what's happening in your code due to the UI interaction. But you're almost certainly writing to the database twice, which seems unwanted.

A simple test:

```
submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        myRef.push().setValue(map);
    }
```

This will try to write the current time in the database. If that doesn't work, check your logcat for error messages.